# How can I get Map<String, String> if I have following class hierarchy?

Tags: java, oop, object, hashmap

I have core object wrapped in a following manner in my class hierarchy.

```
class coreObj {
    Map<String, String> map = new Map<String, String>;
    Map<String, Object> mapObj = new Map<String, Object>;

   Object doSomething(){
     fillMap(map);
     mapObj("somestring",mapObj);
     return mapObj;
   }        
}

class B {
    String some_metadata;
    // stores mapObj as Object
    Object bObj;

    void setbObj(){
       bObj = coreObj.doSomething;
    }
}

class C {
    // stores list of objects of class B
    List<B> listOfB = new List<B>;
}
```

Now, I want to get coreObj.map from another class say D. How should I get it? Also, is there any problem with this design? is there any design pattern which I should apply?

Note: I am an intermediated java programmer. And the code written here is just to give idea about what am I trying to do. It may not be syntactically correct.

Thanks.

Comment: You should tell us what you want to do. Where do you want to access the map? Additionally, this is not valid Java code. You are not allowed to write statements inside a class declaration. You have to wrap them inside method declarations.

Comment: This looks more of some sort of pseudo-java-code instead of valid java code.
Please explain your question more detailed.

Comment: You have no class hierarchy there, they are 3 unrelated classes.

Comment: I apologize for not clarifying  the question properly. The class names are not actual, but I am trying to implement something in a module and these 3 classes are part of it and the flow is as I have explained.

Comment: and what is `fillMap(map)` in coreObj class. and you are keeping map in same map.

Comment: Fillmap will fill some data into map and that map is stored in another map as Object

Comment: @SteffenKreutz: I have updated the question details. Also the code provided is not executable java code. Its just to give some idea about class structure. These classes are part of a bigger module.

Comment: I am sorry alienofearth, but your update does not show any effort or knowledge of an intermediate java programmer to me. still it is not unclear to me what you try to do - there even is no class hierarchy..

Comment: You cannot instanciate an abstract class

Answer (score 0):

There is no hierarchy here, you can access `coreObj.map` with something like that :

```
(Map<String, String>) ((Map<String, Object>) c.getlistOfB().get(i).getbObj()).get(key);
```

But this is really a mess.. You should find a cleaner way to implement your logic.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to achieve from the above code.
But if you just want to access map object from one class to an another class.
Then it's pretty simple.

Let's say you have this class **A** which creates and stores map values

```
public class A{
      private Map<String, String> map = new Map<String, String>;
      private Map<String, Object> mapObj = new Map<String, Object>;

      A(){
        map.put("key","val");
        mapObj.put("key",map);
      }
      //getter
     public Map<String, Object> getMapObj(){
        return mapObj;
    }

}
```

Then in class **B**

```
public class B{
     A a = new A();
     Map<String, Object> mapObj = a.getMapObj();
}
```

Or you declare the instance variable in class A as static variable, to access it without instantiating class A.

It's not clear, what you what to achieve.
Anyways, this would be one of from many approaches to access data between different classes.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you want to get the `mapObj` in `class C`. I hope the following code will suffice your need though its unclear.

```
public class C {

    // stores list of objects of class B
    List<B> listOfB = new ArrayList<B>();

    B b = new B();

    void differentmethod() {
        listOfB.add(new B());

        // toget coreObj.map here
        Map<String, String> mapObj = ((Map<String, String>) ((Map<String, Object>) listOfB.get(0).getbObj()).get("someString"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will quote some of your mistakes :

- you cannot instanciate java.util.map because it is an abstract class, use new HashMap() instead
- coreObj.doSomething : syntax error -> coreObj.doSomething();
- coreObj.doSomething : not static method so you cannot access like that
- List listOfB = new List; List is abstract so use new ArrayList<>() instead.

There are other error but these are some

About the hierachy, these are some example :

- one class that extends another, eg : class B extends C
- a class which have an instance or a list of another class (attribute)

There are another ways to implement hierachy

To get attribute of another class, the best way is to use accessor (getter/setter). Annother way is to make the the attribute static.

```
class coreObj {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String, Object> mapObj = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public Object doSomething(){
        fillMap(map);
        mapObj("somestring",mapObj);
        return mapObj;
    }  

    public Map<String, String> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(Map<String, String> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getMapObj() {
        return mapObj;
    }

    public void setMapObj(Map<String, Object> mapObj) {
        this.mapObj = mapObj;
    }   

}

class B {
    String some_metadata;
    // stores mapObj as Object
    Object bObj;    
    coreObj coreObjAttr;

    void setbObj(){
       bObj = coreObjAttr.doSomething();
    }
}

class C {
    // stores list of objects of class B
    List<B> listOfB = new ArrayList<B>();
}
```